# Vim 8 installation. repository not found

Tags: apt, repository, 16.10, vim

I'm trying to install vim 8 on ubuntu 16.10 by adding the following repository like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vim
```

after doing so apt update gets stuck

```
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu yakkety Release                                 
404  Not Found
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                        
Hit:4 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease         
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                    
Hit:6 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease                           
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease [102 kB]
Get:8 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports InRelease [102 kB]    
Reading package lists...   Done                                                                 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Am I using the wrong repository? I'm following the instructions I found [here](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/09/13/vim-8-0-released-install-ubuntu-16-04/).

Comment: Check in `system settings > software & updates > other software`  and enable the repo there

Comment: Building it from source worked for me by following instructions here https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source

Comment: You could also use [linuxbrew](http://linuxbrew.sh/) to install vim8.

Answer (score 1):

[That repository](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/vim) does not provide packages for 16.10 (Yakkety). Note also that the howto you are reading says it is for 16.04, not 16.10.

Comment: true, sorry. so is there a repository that does provide this for 16.10?

Comment: That could be another question.