# Ubuntu 16.10 repository providing vim 8

Tags: repository, 16.10, vim

Is there a repository that provides vim 8 for ubuntu 16.10? The repository indicated [here](http://sourcedigit.com/20798-vim-vi-improved-for-linux-ubuntu-how-to-install-vim-8-on-ubuntu-16-0416-10-systems/) does not work on 16.10 ([see also here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874906/vim-8-installation-repository-not-found))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[OPTION 1]**

In Ubuntu 16.04 following trick worked.

Try via *ppa:jonathonf/vim*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vim
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vim
```

Check `vim` version with following command.

```
vim -version
```

**[OPTION 2]**

But for 16.10, build from *git source* will be a solution as your [link](http://sourcedigit.com/20798-vim-vi-improved-for-linux-ubuntu-how-to-install-vim-8-on-ubuntu-16-0416-10-systems/) describe.

**[OPTION 3]**

Another option. Download binaries and install with `dpkg` manually. When I install `vim`, its dependency `vim-common`, `vim-runtime`, `xxd` and `vim-tiny` are also installed. Following commands will be install `vim` and those dependencies. Commands should be run one by one.

xxd

```
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/xxd_8.0.0206-0york1~16.04_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i xxd_8.0.0206-0york1~16.04_amd64.deb
```

vim-common

```
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim-common_8.0.0206-0york1~16.04_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i vim-common_8.0.0206-0york1~16.04_all.deb
```

vim-runtime

```
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim-runtime_8.0.0206-0york1~16.04_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i vim-runtime_8.0.0206-0york1~16.04_all.deb
```

vim

```
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim_8.0.0206-0york1~16.04_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i vim_8.0.0206-0york1~16.04_amd64.deb
```

vim-tiny

```
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim-tiny_8.0.0206-0york1~16.04_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i vim-tiny_8.0.0206-0york1~16.04_amd64.deb
```

**[OPTION 4]**

As @[CelticWarrior](https://askubuntu.com/users/589808/celticwarrior)'s suggestion, we can also try with `apt-add-repository`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu xenial main"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu xenial main"
```

After adding repository with `xenial` source.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vim
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is the one that doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry. I updated my answer. You have already found this way. If I have found I will update this answer again.

Comment: If Option 3 works, then you can simply edit the PPA and replace `yakkety` with `xenial`. Change it back as soon as the PPA has support for 16.10, if ever.

Comment: @CelticWarrior, Thanks for your advice. If so we may be able to add with `add-apt-repository` commands. I will add another Option.

Comment: Notice that `ppa:jonathonf/vim` wasn't compiled with Python support.