# How to compile or install Debian version of Vim on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: vim, debian, source-packages

I really like the version/set-up of `vim` that is included with Debian 9 server.

This is **not the same question** as [Ubuntu 16.10 repository providing vim 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875003). I am not asking about how to get Vim 8 on Ubuntu 16.04.

I am asking how I can get the specifically modified version of Vim 8 available on Debian running on Ubuntu 16.04.

Downloading the binaries from [here](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/vim) resulted in a whole mess of dependencies and conflicts.

And I was unable to compile a Debian/Ubuntu package based on [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130894/how-to-build-a-debian-ubuntu-package-from-source) from the source available [here](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/vim) because there doesn't seem to be any `makefile` or `src/config.dist`

```
dpkg-buildpackage: source package vim
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution stretch
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by James McCoy <jamessan@debian.org>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
dpkg-source --before-build billd
 debian/rules build
cp src/config.mk.dist src/auto/config.mk
cp: cannot stat 'src/config.mk.dist': No such file or directory
debian/rules:269: recipe for target 'src/auto/config.mk' failed
make: *** [src/auto/config.mk] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

There's also no makefile to run when running the normal `make`

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

How can I find or compile this modified version of vim that will run on Ubuntu 16.04?

[image: screenshot of Debian vim]

Comment: download it https://packages.debian.org/stretch/vim

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.10 repository providing vim 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875003/ubuntu-16-10-repository-providing-vim-8)

Comment: no, don't download it form debian, see the duplicate I posted, it works for 16.04 as well as 16.10

Comment: @ravery I got the source code from your link there, but am having trouble compiling. No makefile found and don't see compiling instructions in the readme.

Comment: @Panther  The link that you posted is just for getting Vim 8 on Ubuntu 16.04. I want the specifically modified version that is available on Debian.

Comment: I don't know how to create the make file. You can try the binary and see if ubuntu satisfies the depends.

Comment: @ravery Ya, I tried the binary but it creates a whole mess of dependencies and conflicts. :-(